# Resize UIFont Size

Tags: resize, uifont

I'm using the OHAttributedLabel as an UILabel replacement. 
I'd like to calculate the size of my UIFont relying on the length of the text and the height of the OHAttributedLabel.

label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES; doesn't work, OHAttributedLabel doesn't support it and I don't know how I could fix it.

Is there any way to calculate the size of the font?

Thanks in advance,

Nicolai

Answer (score 0):

A potentially simple solution is to use the [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) library instead of OHAttributedLabel.  It supports the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property as long as the number of lines is set to anything greater than 0.

If you need something from OHAttributedLabel that TTTAttributedLabel doesn't provide, perhaps the source can give you some ideas on how to implement it.